# Repeated where() vs multiple collections in c#

Tags: c#, performance, coding-style

I've got a collection of object A's. Each A has a field that correlates is to an object B - of which I have another collection. In other words, each B is attached to a subset of the collection of As (but only conceptually, not in code). This field - correlating A to B - can change during the life of the system. There are system requirements that prevent changing of this structure.

If I need to repeatedly perform operations on each B's set of A's, would it be better to repeated use the Where() method on the collection of A's or create another collection that B owns and a class that manages the add and remove of the relevant items.

Let me see if i can capture this in code:

```
    class A {
      public B owner;
      ...
    }

    class B {
      ...
    }

    class FrequentlyCalledAction {
      public DoYourThing(B current) {
        List<A> relevantItems = listOfAllAItems.Where(x => x.owner == current).ToList()
        foreach (A item in relevantItems) {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Vs:

```
    class A {
      public B owner;
      ...
    }

    class B {
      public List<A> itsItems;
    }

    class FrequentlyCalledAction {
      public void DoYourThing(B current) {
        foreach (A item in current.itsItems) {
          ...
        }
      }
    }

    class AManager {
      public void moveItem(A item, B from, B to) {
        from.itsItems.remove(item);
        to.itsItems.add(item);
      }
    }
```

Comment: How often do you do the thing? How often do the A->B relationships change? How large is the set of As and Bs? Can't B have a reference to A?

Comment: DoYourThing is one of the most frequent calls in the system. A->B relationships change maybe once per every 4 DoYourThing calls. They are both small sets - maybe 50 B, maybe 100 A.

Comment: How often does A have to know who its owner is? Could you just store the A's on their owner and work out who their owner is when you need it?

Comment: There are other parts of the system that require A to know it's owner.

Comment: What did you decide to do in the end?

Answer (score 1):

This primarily depends on the size of the sets. If there are only a few items the overhead that comes with the solution *two* is bigger than the performance gain.

In this case I would use solution *one* since it has a better readability and is less complicated to manage.

If there are thousands of items in the set I would go for solution *two*. The `moveItems` method is an O(n) operation but it seems that there are more reads than writes in your scenario. Therefore you gain more performance through the more structured design.

Comment: You can improve MoveItems to O(1) by using HashSets I think.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it all depend of the size of your collection.  Sol 2 is more complex but faster for big collection while sol1 can be very fast for less than 100/1000 items or so.

Comment: Is there a drawback to space usage on solution 2? Does it matter since they're all really just references? Does the performance increase outweigh it?

Comment: Again it all depend on the collection size but indeed, it's only references that will be stored in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sets are small (~100 items) and they change often (~every 4 iterations) do this, then see if you have a problem.

```
public DoYourThing(B current)
{
    foreach(A item in listOfAllAItems.Where(a => a.owner == current))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't see any point in casting the IEnumrable<A> to an IList<A>.

If this gives you a performance problem I don't think `AManager` is your best answer, although this could depend on how much the relationships change.

Answer (score 0):

If you go for solution 2 it might be worth using a HashSet rather than a List. A HashSet is O(1) for Add & Remove whereas a List is O(1) for Add and O(n) for remove.

Another option is this which has the advantage that users of A & B don't need to remember to use `AManager`:

```
static class GlobalDictionary
{
  private static Dictionary<B,HashSet<A>> dictionary = new Dictionary<B,HashSet<A>>();

  public static HashSet<A> this[B obj]
  {
    // You could remove the set and have it check to see if a Set exists for a B
    // if not you would create it.
    get {return dictionary[obj];}
    set {dictionary[obj] = value;}
  }
} 


class A 
{
  private B owner;  
  public B Owner
  {
    get{ return owner;}
    set
    {
      if (owner != null) GlobalDictionary[owner].Remove(this);

      owner = value;
      GlobalDictionary[owner].Add(this);
    }
  }
}

class B
{
  public B()
  {
    GlobalDictionary[this] = new HashSet<A>();
  }

  public IEnumerable<A> Children
  {
    get
    {
      return GlobalDictionary[this];
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this so it's likely it'll require some tweaks but you should get the idea.

Comment: You might want to think about how to remove B's from the global dictionary when nothing else references them so that the garbage collector can dispose of them.